# Adding bytes and determining flag values

Tags: avr

I am trying to add two hex numbers for example $E2 + $3C which I can do just fine; however, I do not know how to determine the V, N, Z and C flag values?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I have been scratching my head for much too long.

Thanks!

Comment: They are in the status register. Your question needs more context. Are you using C? Assembler? In Assembler, there are several branch instructions based on these flags. In C, look at the bits of `SREG`.

Comment: @UncleO Thanks for the quick response! And this is assembly, my confusion is I thought the flags just hold true and false values? I just do not know how to determine the values for each one. Do I just say the C flag is set when 0xE2 and 0x3C are added?

Comment: Yes, the carry flag is set when `ADD`ing 0xE2 and 0x3C. The MSB of 0xE2 is 1 and the MSB of the result is 0. (It would be set if both numbers had MSB of 1, or only one had and MSB of 1 but the result didn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags are bits in the status register. They are set or cleared by some instructions, (such as ADD or ADC), but not all.

You can look at the status register, `SREG`, directly, but in assembly, there are branch instructions that operate according to these bits. There is a summary of the branch instructions on p. 9 of the [instruction set manual](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf).

Whether or not the flags are set is described in detail in the entries for each instruction, such as for ADD on p. 17.